# Bash Script reboot in certain condition

Tags: bash, shell-script

I make a bash script that calls another two bash script and reboots the system in a condition is match.
The condition is: `REBOOT_REQUIRED`>0

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Declare a variable used as counter in order to count the reboot requests.
declare -i REBOOT_REQUIRED=0

# Script List
RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME='restore-eth-names.sh'
RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER='restore-wifi-driver.sh'

#####################################
# Execute RestoreEthNames.sh script #
#####################################

echo -e "Performing Startup Checks"

chmod +x $RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME
./$RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME
# Store return code
RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME_RET_CODE=$?

if [[ $RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME_RET_CODE == 0 ]]
then
    echo -e "==> Ethernet Configuration: Ok"
else
    echo -e "==> Ethernet Configuration: Fixed"
    ((REBOOT_REQUIRED++))
fi

#######################################
# Execute RestoreWiFiDriver.sh script #
#######################################

chmod +x $RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER
./$RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER
# Store return code
RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER_RET_CODE=$?

if [[ $RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER_RET_CODE == 0 ]]
then
    echo -e "==> WiFi Driver: Ok"
else
    echo -e "==> WiFi Driver: Fixed"
    ((REBOOT_REQUIRED++))
fi

if [[ $REBOOT_REQUIRED > 0 ]]
then
    echo -e "System Reboot in 5 seconds"
    sleep 5
    reboot
fi
```

This script is executed at startup, adding a system service with another installation script:

```bash
################################################
# Create Service to execute scripts on startup #
################################################

if [ -e $SERVICE_FULL_PATH ]; then
   echo "File $SERVICE_FULL_PATH already exists!"
else
   echo -e "[Unit]\nDescription=Startup Script\n\n[Service]\nExecStart=$\/$SCRIPT_STARTUP_CHECKS\n\n[Install]\nWantedBy=default.target" >> $SERVICE_FULL_PATH
   chmod 664 $SERVICE_FULL_PATH
   
   # Enable the service
   systemctl enable $SERVICE_NAME
fi
```

The service is created correctly and the service is enabled.

The problem is that the PC enters into a reboot loop... the PC starts, at the login, after 5 seconds the system reboots again and again.

Comment: After some more thinking: Do you get any of the "Fixed" messages if you launch the script manually?

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that you are using a string comparison operator (`>`). This operator will check if the left-hand-side string is *lexicographically* greater than the right-hand-side string.

What you instead should use is the arithmetic comparison operator `-gt`. The same is true for your checks of the return codes, where you should use `-eq` instead (although it is less of a problem there, the strings representing the two numbers will be equal if the numbers themselves are).

See e.g. [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) or [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29) for more information.

*That said*, in the simple case of a one-digit number (`REBOOT_REQUIRED` should not be able to exceed 2) compared to the "one-digit string" `0` the comparison should still work as expected, so there may be something amiss in the subordinate scripts you call.

Comment: Ha! I was going to source the same link. [Reference in gnu bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Answer (score 2):

You're running your scripts from `./` (`./$RESTORE_ETHERNET_NAME` and `./$RESTORE_WIFI_DRIVER`), and the working directory of services is the root path by default, which means the service actually runs the scripts from `/`, and I guess they are not there.

You should specify the full path for your scripts (and not the relative one), either explicitly, or - assuming that the scripts are located at the same location as the startup script - use the [directory of your startup script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4774063/8529284) in the full path of the scripts. You could also set the `WorkingDirectory` directive to the location of your scripts, but that's not the optimal solution, because that means that if your script runs any other way - and not under a service - they could still fail.

Generally speaking, during debugging, instead of actually rebooting the system, you could just run `echo reboot`. That way the machine wouldn't get into an infinite reboot loop, and you could have seen the output of your script using `systemctl status <your service>`. I assume you would have seen there something such as:

```
./restore-wifi-driver.sh: No such file or directory
```

Or any other error that would have helped you identifying the issue.

And of course - it's always possible that your restore scripts don't work as you expect, don't fix the issue and that would of course lead to an infinite loop.